# Using Azure Logic Apps To Hit A Http Target / Rest Endpoint In Non Prod Environment

Tags: azure, rest, ssl, azure-logic-apps, tls1.2

We are using a Azure Logic Apps workflow as part of our current project. The said workflow is supposed to hit a REST endpoint that we have newly set up as part of our project.

Now, once we deploy the REST endpoint to production, the Logic apps workflow can seamlessly hit it. However, in the dev environment, we have not protected the REST endpoint by a trusted certificate (obviously). Because of this the Logic apps workflow fails to connect to the dev environment REST endpoint, claiming SSL/TLS failure.

My question is, how can we ever dev/test an architecture that requires a Logic apps workflow to hit a HTTP/REST endpoint? Because this TLS/SSL handshake issue will occur every time you don't protect your endpoint with a trusted CA, and frankly, who does that for a dev env?

Comment: Struggling with something similar, did you manage to find a solution

Comment: @RamakantDadhichi it is possible to hit an HTTP endpoint from Logic apps, instead of https. So in dev/test, you test with the http endpoint, just make sure it is publicly accessible. And check if your company's dev/test/staging infra allows you to expose a public http endpoint. If that is possible, LA will be able to connect to it.

Then in prod, expose the same as https.

Comment: Thanks Rajan , my qa env is exposed but Standard logic app throws the Bad request error even when it works from postman. Looks like a standard logic app issue, what do you think?

Comment: @RamakantDadhichi if it throws 400, something must be wrong in the header or other request params.

Comment: My bad should have pasted the complete error,Http request failed as there is an error: 'The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.'.
I doubt it is something to do with the standard logic app

Comment: We were able to get it done with a standard la instance only I think. Which one is the easier to configure? Standard or consumption? We used that one.

Comment: Consumption is easier in terms of setting up, standard gets deployed on an app service. No worries bro, thank you for your time

Comment: @RamakantDadhichi then I believe we used consumption one. Because we did not use any app service instance in our RG.